# .NetのDataTable.Mergeで対象の列がないとエラーが発生する

Tags: .net, vb.net

.Net 4.0(vb.net)で開発しています。

2つのDataTableを結合するために、DataTable.Mergeメソッドを利用しようと考えています。

```
dataTableA.Merge(dataTableB, false, MissingSchemaAction.Error)
```

としたときに、

> ターゲット テーブル B に列 XXX の定義が見つかりません。

とエラーが発生しています。
単純なエラーに見えますが、dataTableAにもdataTableBにも列：XXXは存在しています。

```
dataTableA.WriteXmlSchema("schemaA.xml")
dataTableB.WriteXmlSchema("schemaB.xml")
```

として出力したスキーマのXMLを比較しても一致しています。

エラーメッセージのテーブル名(B)とDataTable.TableNameが一致しているのはdataTableBです。

```
dataTableB.Columns.Contains("XXX")
```

は `True` を返します。

他になにか見落としている点がありそうですか？

---

類似のコーディングをしている箇所が少なかったのでループでImportRowして対応することにしました。
ImportRowもスキーマ合致する必要があるので、何故うまく行くのか不明で納得できませんが。。。

Answer (score 1):

var result = dataTableA.AsEnumerable().Union(dataTableB.AsEnumerable()).CopyToDataTable();

すみません、日本語があまり上手ではありません。

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I wondering why DataTable.Merge method returns error, although (seems) same schema.
To be honest, I'm not want another way.
I just wanted to know WHY.

My English is not so good :)

Comment: I think dataTableA and dataTableB different column name or datatype

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.missingschemaaction?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Excactly.  I tried to compare both schema by "DataTable.WriteXmlSchema" Method and same.